# Help my sister's car won't start

Tags: ford, starting, explorer

(2002 Ford explorer XLT 4x4 v8)
My sister drove her car to work parked it and turned it off, hours later after work she got back into her car went to start it up, the lights worked, the radio works, the engine didn't turn over, replaced the starter and starter solenoid (both 1 piece) with new parts, still didn't turn over, changed out the starter relay with a new one, still nothing, I got a check light, checked the starter wires, the bigger wire lit up constantly while the little wire wouldn't light up, got her to try turning it on while I was checking the wire and it still didn't light, so the last thing I can think of checking is the neutral safety switch but I have no idea how to check that without just replacing it, any comments or suggestions is very appreciated!!! Also there isn't any security lights on the dash showing up if that helps narrow it down.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: If you know what you are doing then you can short out the neutral safety switch which, obviously, tests it by absence... Did see someone get it wrong once and the engine started and drove off the ramp, only problem was it was 6ft in the air...